# How do I find the number of times I've iterated through a foreach loop?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

If I'm trying to find the number of times I've iterated through a foreach loop in java is there a better way to do it than this?

```
int i = 0;
for (Button button : levelBtns) {
    button = new Button(160, 40 + (i * 50), 100, 40);
    i++;
}
```

I know I could just use a normal for loop and have an iterator, i, but I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this with a foreach.Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: As Jon Skeet pointed out, the code above assigns the new button instance to the iteration variable. Oops. Based on other comments, I believe the most practical thing to use is a normal loop. Here's the version I'm going with. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
Button[] levelBtns = new Button[6];
for (int i = 0; i < levelBtns.length; i++) {
    levelBtns[i] = new Button(160, 40 + (i * 50), 100, 40);
}
```

Comment: Do you need the information in the loop or after the loop?

Comment: I believe you have already posted the best solution. However, if you are concerned about what iteration your currently on, why not switch to a traditional for loop.

Comment: The solution is completely fine.

Comment: I am assuming `levelBtns` is an array or a `Collection` of some sort, therefore the number of iterations would be `lvlButtons.length` or `lvlButtons.size()` ?

Comment: Your code is currently pointless anyway, as you're assigning a new value to the iteration variable... which does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an Iterable, but a Collection or array, you're iterating through, and you need the number of iterations after the loop, just use Collection.size() method or *length* field of an array to get the size of it, which is also the number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution for a foreach-loop. Otherwise you could use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<levelBtns.lenght; i++) {
  levelBtns[i] = new Button(160, (i + 40) * 50, 100, 40);
}
```

Comment: OP already mentioned `I know I could just use a normal for loop and have an iterator`, But I believe this is the clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is ok and it's general. But a possible way is

You can get the counter value  by getting , If it is a List then `levelBtns.size()`  of if an array then `array.length`